# confusion about the meaning of confess

Tags: vocabulary

I confessed to a girl who I love. (I told her I love you)

Can I use confess like this?

I heard some people I can and some people I can't.

Answer (score 1):

"Confess" means admit to a fact that is either a crime or sin, or a fact that you are embarrassed or ashamed of.

In the given phrase it isn't clear what you are confessing.  I suppose you mean that you are admitting the fact that you love the girl  (and you are embarrassed by this)  but it *could* mean that you are admitting to a crime that you have committed to your girlfriend.

So to make your sentence clear you need use an object or phrase to say *what* you are confessing:

> I confessed my love to Mary.

> I confessed to Mary that I love her.

Or

> I confessed to a girl I love that I'd broken her favourite plate.

Comment: thank you. Then is using the word "confess" the most natural way to say I told that I love her or did you make a sentence with confess just because I made a sentence with confess? So what I mean is that is confess specialized for letting someone know that I love them?

Comment: @도라에몽1 no, "confess" is not specialized for telling someone you love them, and is not usually used that way. I've only ever seen it in webcomics badly translated from Chinese

Comment: @도라에몽1 There's many natural ways to describe telling someone you love them. "Confess" is one of them. "Declare" is another. "Shout it from the rooftops" is a third. They have different feels. "Confess" is when you re reluctant to reveal it to them, and it sounds like it's done quietly, or by accident, like when you're drunk.

Comment: "confess" is not specially about love.  It is about either admitting a crime or sin.  Or it can mean admitting something you are embarrassed about.  You might be embarrassed about your feelings, so in that context "confess" might be a good word.